# Sliding elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to slide some content in my website, i tried running this code but the sliding only happens at the first click and can't find a clue why. Here are my code snippets : 
Html :

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  $(".block").animate({
    right: 85
  }, {
    duration: 800,
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $(".block:gt(0)").css("right", now);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #abc;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="go">Run »</button>
</p>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Try `right : "+=85"`, by doing `right: 85` you're setting right to 85 on each click

Comment: As @Lauromine said, you are using a fixed distance for animation. You need to "add" to the previous "right" with +=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `'+=85'`.

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  $(".block").animate({
    right: '+=85'
  }, {
    duration: 800,
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $(".block:gt(0)").css("right", now);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #abc;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button id="go">Run »</button>
</p>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

By the way, I don't know what exactly is the use for `step` function here.

Comment: Thank you bro thats what I needed. I'm new to javascript and it's bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the `+=` to the number check the snippet. So on every click it will add up 85 pixels to the right `+=` means {right = right + 85} or also you can use `-=` {right = right - 85}  for negetive accumulators

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  $(".block").animate({
    right: '+=85'
  }, {
    duration: 800,
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $(".block:gt(0)").css("right", now);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #abc;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button id="go">Run »</button>
</p>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```